How do I instantiate a collection in a custom control directly in XAML?
For some controls, such as ComboBox, the following are valid ways to add items into the Items collection instead of using the ItemsSource property:
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Item1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="{x:Bind Item2Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
</ComboBox>

<!-- OR -->
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item1" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="{x:Bind Item2Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>

<!-- OR -->
<ComboBox>
    <x:String>Item1</x:String>
    <!-- Is it possible to somehow use x:Bind or Binding in these x:String elements? -->
    <x:String>Item2</x:String>
</ComboBox>

The following lines in the documentation for the ComboBoxItem Class seem to imply that in all three of these examples, (even the one using x:String elements) the items are being automatically wrapped inside ComboBoxItems:

The ComboBoxItem class provides the container for items displayed in a
ComboBox control. You populate the ComboBox by adding objects directly
to its Items collection or by binding its ItemsSource property to a
data source. When items are added to the ComboBox, a ComboBoxItem
container is created automatically for each item in the collection.
You can specify the look of the ComboBoxltem by setting the ComboBox's
ItemContainerStyle property to a Style with a TargetType of
ComboBoxItem.

How would I make a custom control that behaves in a similar way? i.e. CustomControl which automatically wraps data added to it's Items collection inside CustomControlItem containers.
I've been able to do something close by adding an ObservableCollection<string> Items DependencyProperty to my custom control. This isn't quite what I want though, since it only works with x:String elements, which I can't x:Bind the value of (afaik).

“custom control”, do you mean Templated Control or User Control in UWP?

@JunjieZhu-MSFT User Control

In addition to “string”, what content do you want to add?

@JunjieZhu-MSFT It would depend on what I need whatever control I'm making to do. Some might just need strings, bools, and ints, others might need more complex classes too, maybe I could just have it call the ToString method of whatever it's wrapping somehow?...
Point being I'm more interested in how ComboBox automatically wraps objects inside of ComboBoxItems, so I can copy that functionality for controls that I make.

Sorry, currently UWP does not have an API that can meet your needs. I tried using ItemsPresenter but I can't get the string, bool etc on the code side, I can only get the control object(like TextBlock).

If all you want to do is load a combox (or ListView) with "user controls", then create and load your user controls into an observable collection and assign that to the ItemsSource. Data templates are pretty powerful and UC's in this case may be overkill; especially since you don't seem to have a particular design in mind. The underlying "data object", and how "smart" it is, influences one's design choices.
